# Wicket - order of adding components in Java matters?

Tags: java, wicket

I have created a simple wicket form with a DropDownChoice, a submit button and two TextFields, in order to try some model-chaining. The html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DropDownTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <form wicket:id="selectForm">   
            <select wicket:id="dropDown"></select>              
            <input type="submit" wicket:id="bt"/>           
            <input type="text" wicket:id="age"/>
            <input type="text" wicket:id="name"/>           
        </form>             
    </body>
</html>
```

and the java code:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

private class Person implements Serializable {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(){};

    public Person(int pAge, String pName) {     
        age = pAge;
        name = pName;           
    }

    public int getAge() {return age;}

    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

}   

public List<Person> getPersons() {

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person(34, "Hanna"));
    persons.add(new Person(17, "Ivan"));
    persons.add(new Person(64, "Carol"));   
    return persons;
}

private Form form;
private DropDownChoice<Person> dropDown;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);      

    Model<Person> personModel = new Model<Person>();

    dropDown = new DropDownChoice<Person>("dropDown", personModel, getPersons(), 
            new ChoiceRenderer<Person>("name"));

    form = new Form("selectForm");

    form.add(new TextField("name", new PropertyModel(personModel, "name")));
    form.add(new TextField("age", new PropertyModel(personModel, "age")));      
    form.add(dropDown);

    form.add(new Button("bt"));     

    add(form);
}   
}
```

The dropdownchoice and the two textfields share the same model (personModel), so when the user selects a Person from the dropdownchoice and submits the form clicking the button and the page reloads, the two fields get their values from the person selected via the model. This works as expected and I get no errors. Now, if I change the order in which I add the components to the form from this (working):

```
form.add(new TextField("name", new PropertyModel(personModel, "name")));
form.add(new TextField("age", new PropertyModel(personModel, "age")));      
form.add(dropDown);
```

to this (not working)

```
form.add(dropDown);
form.add(new TextField("name", new PropertyModel(personModel, "name")));
form.add(new TextField("age", new PropertyModel(personModel, "age")));
```

I get an error when I submit the form:

> Method [public int com.asbjorntest.HomePage$Person.getAge()]. Can't convert null value to a primitive class: int for setting it on com.asbjorntest.HomePage$Person@71460b93

I understand that the error comes from the fact that I am submitting the "age" textfield without any value and that can't be converted to an int in my Person class. But why does this error only happen if I add the dropdownchoice before adding the textfields in the Java code? Or maybe I should ask: why does it NOT happen when I add it after? Does the order in which I add components to a form or to a page in the java code matter, or am I missing something completely here?

Thanks in advance for any answers or clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order in `HTML` is irrelevent. The order in `Java` can be relevent, as order of the  components determines how they are validated.

As you put the `DropDownChoice` latest, the `null` `age` from the `TextField`  will be overridden by the value that you selected in the dropdown and all works fine.

If you put your components the other way around, your `age` will be `null` (value from `TextField` and you will get your error.

To be short: **be careful when multiple components edit the same model value**.

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember, it's discouraged to share models among components, and therefore it's recommended to create a new one for each component.
Note, that when you create the `personModel` initially doesn't have a concrete person attached, I suspect that it's created when it's added to the page. So the person of the model is null when text fields are created and added to the form.

All in all, I would recommend you something like that:

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);      

    Person person = new Person();
    form = new Form("selectForm");

    dropDown = new DropDownChoice<Person>("dropDown", new Model<Person>(person), getPersons(), new ChoiceRenderer<Person>("name"));
        form.add(dropDown);

    // I think you can use person as first parameter, else use new Model<Person(person),
    form.add(new TextField("name", new PropertyModel(person, "name")));
    form.add(new TextField("age", new PropertyModel(person, "age")));      

    form.add(new Button("bt"));     

    add(form);
}
```

Anyway, It's been quite at time since I would use Wicket, so I may be completely wrong :P

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer! I am new to Wicket and I was following the guide/tutorial from apache, where it is described that sharing models can be used to do model-chaining where the model-outcome of one component (in my case the dropdown) can be the model-source for another component. But I suppose that, as @RobAu comments I have to be careful with the order because of the validation issues. Regards!